# union of two sub- vector spaces can not be the complete vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $W_1 ,W_2$ are sub-vector spaces of $V$

How to prove that if $W_1 \cup W_2 $ is a sub-vector space of $V$ then $W_1 \subset W_2$ or $W_2 \subset W_1$ ?

Comment: What if $W_1\not\subset W_2$ and $W_2\not\subset W_1$?

Comment: Is $W_1\cup W_2$ closed under scalar multiplication? What about addition? (What happens if they are distinct lines in a plane? Two planes in space?)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown @ Milo Brandt  this is all the information in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $W_1 \nsubseteq W_2$ and $W_2 \nsubseteq W_1$. So we can pick some $0 \neq x\in W_1$ such that $x \notin W_2$ and some $0 \neq y \in W_2$ such that $y \notin W_1$. But $x,y \in W_1 \cup W_2$. Since $W_1 \cup W_2$ is a subspace of $V$, we must have $x+y \in W_1 \cup W_2$. This implies that either $x+y \in W_1$ or $x+y \in W_2$. Since $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces, we have $y = x+y -x \in W_1$ or $x = x+y -y \in W_2$ contradicting our assumption!